# Please help identify parallel universe novel

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

Years ago (late 70's/early 80's) I read a science fiction story which I think was a novel, though I'm not sure. In the story, there was a secret group that had developed technology for travelling between parallel universes. In the multi-verse of the story, there were a great many time lines with alternate US histories and in particular differences in who signed historic documents - I think the Declaration of Independence was the main one, though it could have been the constitution. If I recall the story correctly, there were collectors who trafficked in rare alternate versions of these documents (our version was quite commonplace).

I remember one scene (the first chapter?) in which a historian who specialized in the document in question was visiting the National Archives and reading through it and fainted when he got to the signatures. Someone had substituted a rare version of the document for the actual one from our universe.

Can someone identify the title and author of this story?

Comment: Sounds a bit like North American Confederacy series by L. Neil Smith, One single word in the Declaration of Independence differs and the US becomes the North American Confederation, a libertarian society.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it isn't L. Neil Smith. That was my original thought for most obvious answer so I went through his writings before asking the question.

Comment: Sound like Sliders http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112167/ The the dates on this are 1995 - 2000

Comment: I watched every episode of Sliders as they premiered, even after the show had clearly jumped the shark. No, it wasn't Sliders. I'm pretty sure I read it in high school so no later than 1981.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the name of the story I was looking for. It's called *[The Whenabouts of Burr](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3944640-the-whenabouts-of-burr)* and it's written by Michael Kurland.

> Someone has taken the original document of the U.S. Constitution and substituted another. The substitute is identical, just as old, and equally authentic -- except it has been signed by Aaron Burr! It contradicts history, but it is real and there for everyone to see! Such a crime calls for out-of-this-world detective work. There must be alternate Americas -- and one of them must be an American union that Burr helped shape. With a few impossible coins, the path is indicated...and the search for THE WHENABOUTS OF BURR begins! It's a hunt through all the alternate-universe Americas that might have been -- with Alexander Hamilton to point the way and Aaron Burr to block it!