# Alt-history based on the Hamilton-Burr duel

Tags: story-identification, novel, alternate-history

In the 1980s, I think, I read a novel or a series whose alternate history was based on Alexander Hamilton surviving, if not winning, his duel with Aaron Burr.

That alternate outcome led to a whole underground organization dedicated to changing something or other--I didn't know enough history at the time to really grasp what was going on. Does anyone have any idea what I'm talking about?

I think it involved an alternate outcome to the American Civil War, as well.

This [unanswered question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108657/looking-for-novel-novella-80s-90s-about-history-revisionism) seems like it might be about the same story.

Comment: I read an anthology with a bunch of stories like this.

Comment: @Spencer [Alternate Presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_Presidents)?

Comment: @JohnRennie No, it had a different cover with Lincoln and a robot (illustrating a relatively famous story IIRC). I would dig it out of a box if OP comments that it might be an anthology.

Comment: @JohnRennie There were several of these alternate history anthologies in the early and mid 90's.

Comment: Alternate presidents, alternate Kennedys, several alternate generals, and "by every other fame"

Comment: @JohnRennie OP's story looks more like a time travel story (species time police acc. to linked Q) than an alternate history one, however.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/please-help-identify-parallel-universe-novel

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a long shot¹, but how about [The Whenabouts of Burr](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3944640-the-whenabouts-of-burr) by Michael Kurland?

[image: The Whenabouts of Burr]

> Someone has taken the original document of the U.S. Constitution and substituted another. The substitute is identical, just as old, and equally authentic -- except it has been signed by Aaron Burr! It contradicts history, but it is real and there for everyone to see! Such a crime calls for out-of-this-world detective work. There must be alternate Americas, and one of them must be an American union that Burr helped shape. With a few impossible coins, the path is indicated and the search for the whenabouts of Burr begins! It's a hunt through all the alternate-universe Americas that might have been with Alexander Hamilton to point the way and Aaron Burr to block it!

It doesn't match everything in your description, but it is alternate history in the sense that are lots of alternate Americas and in some of these Hamilton is still alive. It's also time travel in the sense that time is different in these different Americas so going to them means going back into the past. There are alternate Americas where the civil war ended differently or didn't happen at all.

---

<sub>¹ No pun intended - honestly!</sub>

Comment: You're not throwing away your long shot 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ah, yes :-) The pun was genuinely unintended.